# Expandable ListView with Parse.com

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, expandablelistview, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement expandable listview in my application instead of my regular ListView..All went well with regular listview but i can't figure out how to use Expandable ListView with Parse.com and i can't find any examples to help me out. Anyone has any ideas?

Hereunder my code for the regular ListView

```
public class ListViewPost extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<UsersPostsGet> UsersPostsGet = null;
List<ParseObject> ob;
private ArrayList<UsersPostsGet> arraylist;
String reportV;
String XXX;
public int postion;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;



public ListViewPost(Context context, List<UsersPostsGet> UsersPostsGet) {
    mContext = context;
    this.UsersPostsGet = UsersPostsGet;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<UsersPostsGet>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(UsersPostsGet);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView username;
    TextView userpost;
    TextView posttime;
    ImageView thumbs;
    ImageView port;
    ImageView stuatsicon;
    ImageView attachpic;


}

public int getCount() {
    return UsersPostsGet.size();
}

public UsersPostsGet getItem(int position) {
    return UsersPostsGet.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postlayout, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nickname);
        holder.userpost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userpost);
        holder.posttime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.posttime);
        holder.thumbs = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbdown);
        holder.stuatsicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.statusicon);
        holder.port = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.attachpic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.attachpic);


        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.username.setText(UsersPostsGet.get(position).getUsername());
    holder.userpost.setText(UsersPostsGet.get(position).getUserpost());
    holder.posttime.setText(UsersPostsGet.get(position).getPosttime());


    ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(mContext);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://www.nogomistars.com/wallpaper/ahmed-mekki-1898-25363-3138242.jpg", holder.port);


    XXX = UsersPostsGet.get(position).getId();

    reportV = UsersPostsGet.get(position).getReport();


    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).geturl().contentEquals("")) {
        holder.attachpic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus().contentEquals("green")) {
        holder.stuatsicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.green2);
    }

    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus().contentEquals("lightgreen")) {
        holder.stuatsicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.lightgreenstatus);
    }

    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus().contentEquals("yellow")) {
        holder.stuatsicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yallowstatus);
    }

    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus().toString()
            .contentEquals("orange")) {
        holder.stuatsicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.orangestatus);
    }

    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus().toString()
            .contentEquals("red")) {
        holder.stuatsicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.redstatus);
    }

    if (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus().contentEquals("blue")) {
        holder.stuatsicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluestatus);
    } 



    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank


            intent.putExtra("username",
                    (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getUsername()));

            intent.putExtra("userpost",
                    (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getUserpost()));

            intent.putExtra("posttime",
                    (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getPosttime()));

            intent.putExtra("status",
                    (UsersPostsGet.get(position).getstatus()));

            intent.putExtra("url",
                    (UsersPostsGet.get(position).geturl()));



            mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain the *exact* problem you are having.

Comment: I just want to have an example to the expandable listview with parse.com in order to understand the usability for it.

Comment: Parse offers `ParseQueryAdapter` that implements many features for you. It only works with `ListView` but you should consider if all the features it provides outweigh implementing an `ExpandableListView`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make use of a BaseAdapter for an Expandable list view. Create an adapter extended from BaseExpandableListAdapter. The getView() method should be replaced with the getGroupView() and getChildView() for Group Header View and Child View respectively. You might also need two different layouts for the Group and Child views.

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) is one of the best example. You can find lots of tutorials that discuss ExpandableListView.

Comment: He wants to use the Parse sdk

Comment: Thanks for ur reply I will check it out..is there any one for prase??

Comment: My ExpandableListAdapter explanation was meant for the code that you had provided in the question. I am not aware of an adapter for Expandable list view in the Parse SDK.